# Transform asteroid rotation to heliocentric ecliptic coordinates

Tags: asteroids, coordinate

I'm working with data from the [DAMIT database](https://astro.troja.mff.cuni.cz/projects/asteroids3D/web.php?page=db_description) of asteroid shape models.  I'm adding them to a visualization in which the sun is at [0, 0, 0] and the X, Y axes constitute the ecliptic plane of the solar system.

Each asteroid model comes with some attributes that define its orientation and spin:

- λ (ecliptic longitude),
- β (ecliptic latitude)
- P (sidereal rotation period)
- φ0 (initial rotation angle)
- JD0 (initial date).

I've applied the matrix formulas suggested by the folks at DAMIT:

[image: ecliptic rotation]

in which

[image: matrix definitions[2]]

This is where I get confused.  My understanding is that my visualization uses a heliocentric ecliptic coordinate system.

I set `r_ast` to the XYZ location of a vertex in my visualization.  I'm not sure this is correct.

Then I compute `r_ecl` from the equation above.  But I think variables λ and β are angles in a geocentric ecliptic coordinate system and I need to do some transformation into heliocentric ecliptic coordinates.

Is my approach correct and if so, how can I convert the asteroid's rotation to my visualization's heliocentric ecliptic coordinate system?

Comment: $\lambda$ and $\beta$ are the co-ordinates of the asteroid's pole in a heliocentric ecliptic frame so I think you are OK if this is also what your visualization is using

Comment: Thanks @astrosnapper.  How can you tell λ  and β are heliocentric rather than geocentric in this case?  From this table of ecliptic coordinate notation on Wikipedia I guessed they were geocentric: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_coordinate_system#Spherical_coordinates

Comment: Technically it doesn't specify the origin (and it should) but since the asteroid is in orbit around the Sun and not the Earth, heliocentric vs geocentric seems most likely

Comment: Thank you @astrosnapper. One more point of clarification. Is it correct to set `r_ast` to the asteroid's heliocentric ecliptic rectangular coordinates? The website describes `r_ast` as a vector in the "asteroid co-rotating coordinate frame" but I'm not sure what that means here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r_ast` is a vector that goes from the center of the asteroid to each vertex of the shape model as if you had stuck a set of rods in the center of a potato and pointing along the long axis, to the pole on top and 90 degrees to these to give X,Y,Z directions.

The matrices above that you give then transform these `r_ast` vectors for the co-ordinates of the surface of the asteroid into the ecliptic plane as a function of time as the asteroid rotates, giving you `r_ecl`. It says in the Kaasalainen paper (I think) that `r_ecl` has an origin shifted to the center of the asteroid. If you are wanting a visualization of what the asteroid looks like relative to the Earth or Sun etc, then you will need to calculate the Sun->asteroid vector and the Sun->Earth vector using e.g. [JPL HORIZONS](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) and using the Vector Table ephemeris type or a programmatic wrapper to this (e.g. [astroquery](https://astroquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jplhorizons/jplhorizons.html)) or the [NAIF SPICE toolkit](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/toolkit.html) and getting or generating a SPK kernel file for the asteroid (the normal e.g. `de430.bsp` JPL planetary ephemeris will handle the Sun->Earth part)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was really helpful and I've made a lot of progress on my project.  I've asked a follow up question in case you are interested in seeing where your answer took me :)  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29575/rendering-asteroid-orientation-as-seen-from-earth