# Rendering asteroid orientation as seen from Earth

Tags: asteroids, rotation, orbital-mechanics

I am writing a program to render an asteroid as seen from various parts of the solar system.  My goal is to roughly reproduce the [image of Cacus](http://astro.troja.mff.cuni.cz/projects/asteroids3D/php.php?script=db_sky_projection&model_id=1863&jd=2443568.0) according to information on its DAMIT [detail page](http://astro.troja.mff.cuni.cz/projects/asteroids3D/web.php?page=db_asteroid_detail&asteroid_id=1046).

Here is my approach:

1. Create a solar system at JD0=2443568.0.  The axes of the visualization are arranged according to the ecliptic with positive X axis in the direction of the vernal equinox and other axes according to the right-hand rule.  Earth is positioned at t=JD0.  ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UjqP.png))
2. Place the asteroid at (0, 0, 0) and begin to rotate the object according to the matrix multiplication described by the [Description page](http://astro.troja.mff.cuni.cz/projects/asteroids3D/web.php?page=db_description) and [Kaasalainen & Torppa 2001](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.546.7648&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

   - φ0=0 and t=JD0, so there is no initial Z axis rotation
   - Latitude β is -63, so rotate 90 - (-63) = 153 degrees on the Y axis ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPulB.png))
   - Longitude λ is 251, so rotate the object 251 degrees anticlockwise around the Z axis of the ecliptic ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Iv58.png))
3. Using ephemeris from the NASA/JPL Small Body Database, move Cacus to its position in orbit at JD0. ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZESc.png))
4. Move the camera to Earth's position at JD0 and point it at the asteroid. ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IhIa.png))

My final rendering does not match the [projection from DAMIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Va8r.png).  I understand that there are factors like light-time correction that I'm not including, but it looks completely different.

What is wrong with my approach to rotating the asteroid on its spin axis?

[image: My rendering of Cacus]

(The work-in-progress visualization is online [here](http://www.ianww.com/asteroid-spin/))

Comment: Obvious questions first: Did you convert the $\beta$ and $\lambda$ angles to radians before attempting to use them in a rotation matrix?

Comment: I am indeed converting the angles to radians

Comment: How are you determining where the Earth is at jd0?

Comment: @cms If you are willing to read code, here is the function I wrote to compute heliocentric coords from ephemeris: https://gist.github.com/typpo/e20da5a9976edd28511240b9248f00fe  I am using ephem for EM Barycenter from https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?planet_pos

Comment: @cms I've detailed my process for heliocentric position here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29575/rendering-asteroid-orientation-as-seen-from-earth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the paper by [M. Kaasalainen, J. Torppa, and K. Muinonen](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.546.7648&rep=rep1&type=pdf), equation (1) is:

$$ \vec r_{ast} = R_z(\omega(t-t_0)+\phi_0) R_y(\hat\beta) R_z(\lambda) \vec r_{ecl} $$

To reverse this equation you must reverse the order of the rotations *and* the rotation angles:
$$ \vec r_{ecl} = R_z(-\lambda)R_y(-\hat\beta)R_z(-\omega(t-t_0)-\phi_0) \vec r_{ast} $$

From your description, you reversed the order of the rotations but not the rotation angles.

Comment: Looking at the paper and at the DAMIT description webpage, I can't reconcile the two transformations. They claim to use the same handedness for their rotations but the two equations are inverses of each other.

Comment: Thank you @cms.  Given ̂ = 90 - , t=t0, and phi0=0, my final transformation is  ⃗_=(−)(−(90-) )(0)⃗_. I'm first rotating -(90-) =-153 around Y, then -=-251 around Z.

[It still doesn't look quite right](https://i.imgur.com/JGigJci.png), but a small manual rotation matches the DAMIT rendering. Maybe it's accounted for by minor differences in ephemeris or other factors. I'm a little skeptical but at this point it's hard to be sure.  I've also updated the [interactive rendering](http://www.ianww.com/asteroid-spin/) accordingly.